# Make the 'edit pending' link on tag wikis link go to the review item

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

The tag wiki page shows an 'edit pending' button instead of an 'edit' button when there's a pending edit:

[image]

The button looks like it should go to the page for the suggested edit, but it actually only goes to `/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits`. I don't like this, and as a user without edit privileges (or edit-approving privileges, for that matter), I want to be able to see the pending edit. Only out of curiosity, but I still want to see it.

Comment: Yes, as a possible rationale for this would simply be to see if any further efforts to make further edits would be necessary.